# Order by listagg is not ascending according the list data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have problem how to ascending the data according the list. For example, i have a table field names mhn.kod_urusan. i want to show the result according the list that i type.The problem is the data not follow what i type in the list.
**"and mhn.kod_urusan in ('PBPTG','PBMT')"**

```
This is my query:-
select LISTAGG (upper(aa.kod_urusan), ', ') within Group (order by aa.kod_urusan asc) as daerah
from
(select  distinct
mhn.kod_urusan,kc.nama nm
from
mohon mhn, kod_urusan ku, kod_caw kc
where
 mhn.kod_urusan = ku.kod(+)
and mhn.kod_caw = kc.kod(+)
and (mhn.trh_masuk  <= sysdate )
and mhn.kod_urusan in ('PBPTG','PBMT')  
and mhn.kod_caw = '01'
order by mhn.kod_urusan asc )aa


This is the result:-
 --Daerah--
  PBMT, PBPTG
```

Anyone know what the problem?

Answer (score 0):

PBMT is shorter than PBPTG so result is ok

if you need custom sort order, you have to add some int column to table `mohon`, let it be `int myordercol`;

for all different values in `kod_urusan` you should use queries like:

```
update mohon set myordercol = 1 where kod_urusan='PBPTG';
update mohon set myordercol = 2 where kod_urusan='PBMT';
.. and so on, so in such way you're establishing custom order for this columns
```

after this you will need to change your order by clauses to use this column as sorting field

Comment: the problem now is I want to display the data according to what my same like i type in the list. I do not want asscending or descending data. i have remove the asc or desc but the list still not display what i want.how to do that?

Comment: to implement distinct and group oracle have to sort data, so you always will get sorted data, either asc or desc, but sorted, to avoid this you need more complex system with some field, where you will store you preferable sorting order and sort by this field

Comment: i have try your way but this not what i want, i just want to display exactly whatever i put in the list.For example when i pun mhn.kod_urusan in (PBPPA,PPPTG,PBMT,PADN,PZAD). 1 want the data display same like input list.:(

Answer (score 0):

PBMT,  PBPTG is sorted ascending.  If you want it reversed, sort descending.

Comment: the problem now is I want to display the data according to what my same like i type in the list. I do not want asscending or descending data. i have remove the asc or desc but the list still not display what i want.how to do that?

Comment: To guarantee a specific order you have to sort by something.